# Is there any lore that explains why the feral child is human only

Tags: pathfinder-1e, druid, archetype

So I was thinking of making a druid a skimmed through the archetypes to see if there was anything good, under racial archetypes saw the [Feral Child](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/human/feral-child-druid-human/) it was listed as only human for some reason. I showed my dm the flavor text and he also found it odd. That made me curious so I came here to ask.

The flavor text reads as follows

> The feral child is an archetype of the druid class, available to human druids.
>
> Some youths, abandoned in the wilderness and then raised by animals,
> are so connected with their adoptive home and family that they become
> feral. Suspicious of civilized society, these foundlings often choose
> allegiance to the wild over their human forebears.

Although it specifically calls for humans I find it hard to believe that humans are the only race who throw unwanted children into the wilderness. Is there anything I'm missing that makes it so that only humans can have this class?

With all that in mind, I ask the question: why are humans the only race that can access feral child. Since we obviously can't know what the devs were thinking it would probably be more effective to look for lore so let's go with that.

Comment: Are you asking why the *designers* chose to mark the archetype as human-only? Or are you asking if there is any lore in the book the archetype was published in (the Advanced Race Guide) that explains why the archetype is human-only?

Comment: @ObliviousSage Lore

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### There is no additional lore available about the Feral Child archetype.

You have already read the sum total of the lore available about the Feral Child archetype. There is no other lore available about it, whether in the Advanced Race Guide (where the archetype was published) or in any other Pathfinder book.

This is pure speculation on my part, but the Feral Child is likely human-only for the same reason that the Wanderer monk archetype and Buccaneer gunslinger archetype are human-only: because they were published in a book about race-specific options and humans were an available race that needed more options. In the same vein, the book contains race-specific non-magical equipment, with no lore explaining why other races are incapable of using said equipment.